# Facebook SDK 4.4.0 : is getLoginUrl deprecated?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the most recent version of Facebook SDK and I am wondering if it is still okay to pass the scope as an argument in the getLoginUrl method.

```
$login_url = $helper->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'public_profile', 'email'));
```

The documentations says getLoginUrl is a feature that was removed after PHP SDK 3.2.3
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-getLoginUrl/4.0.0

Is it still reliable to use getLoginUrl?

Comment: It was removed from the BaseFacebook. It still existing in some helper classes. You have to look in the documentation for the helper you are using

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).